# Outlined MaterialButton doesn't show any border

Tags: android, button, material-design

I'm trying to build a layout with a bordered button as shown below (Expected behavior). From Material design documentation I read about Outlined Material Button that seemed to be perfect for my purpose. I defined the button in my layout, providing stroke width and stroke color but it isn't showing any border, what am I doing wrong?

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Change name"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/listTextView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/listTextView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/listTextView2"
            app:strokeColor="@color/green"
            app:strokeWidth="10dp" />
```

Expected behavior:

[image]

Current behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just add this attribute to your `MaterialButton`

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
```

avoid to add it to your main theme.

example:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Change name"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/listTextView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/listTextView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/listTextView2"
            app:strokeColor="@color/green"
            app:strokeWidth="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this in your build.gradle app

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

I think it is a bug in google material.

**Update:** I Tested just right now. Use dependency in Gradle app below

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05
```

and in your material button XML, add style

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
```

it might not show in your xml preview but it will show when you run the app

Comment: It's weird that in alpha03, 04 and 05 the bug persists, but in 02 it's solved? shouldn't be solved for all releases after 02 !? Thanks for point that out.

Answer (score 3):

try removing transparent background and style from your xml. and also make sure to change the style to MaterialComponents.

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"> 

 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="works"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

Comment: Not working unfortunately, no border shown and grey background

Comment: can you please post your layout xml file.

Comment: there's nothing more than a constraintlayout as container

Comment: oh oh! I don't know what magic is making your xml not working. may be try using RelativeLayout. just give it a try.

Comment: It was a theme issue! By changing my theme from Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar to Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar it works

Comment: okay nice! I have already mentioned about the updated code. anyway! glad it worked ;)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
 <style name="oval_button_outline" 
     parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_color</item>
</style>



 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/start_login"
        style="@style/oval_button_outline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.09"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_color"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
        app:strokeColor="@color/dark_color"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

Adding android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
     android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
     style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Pick Date"
     android:background="@drawable/register_edittext_background"
     android:textSize="12sp"

     app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
/>
```

Comment: simply adding `app:backgroundTint` worked for me